# Finding values $a \in M = (0, \infty)$ so that $(M\setminus\{a\}, \circ)$ is a group given $x \circ y = f(x)^{g(y)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $M = (0, \infty)$. Find all real numbers $a > 0$, such that there exist two functions $f : M \rightarrow M$ and $g : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $(M \setminus \{a\}, \circ)$ is a group, given that $x \circ y = f(x)^{g(y)}, \forall x, y \in M$.

Given that $(M \setminus \{a\}, \circ)$ is a group, I first attempted to find out what exactly happens once we apply the transformations $x \rightarrow 1_M$ and $y \rightarrow 1_M$, where $1_M \in M$ is the identity element of the group. Therefore, we know that $x \circ 1_M = x, \forall x \in M$ and respectively $1_M \circ x = x, \forall x \in M$. Additionally, we can use the fact that $x \circ 1_M = 1_M \circ x, \forall x \in M$. Thus, we obtain:

$x \circ 1_M = f(x)^{g(1_M)} \Leftrightarrow f(x)^{g(1_M)} = x, \forall x \in M$ (1)

$1_M \circ x = f(1_M)^{g(x)} \Leftrightarrow f(1_M)^{g(x)} = x, \forall x \in M$ (2)

(2) is particularly interesting because it resembles $e^{\ln x} = x$. However, this is where I am stuck. I thought about taking the natural log of both sides but $g(M) \subset \mathbb{R}$, so we might get $g(x) \leq 0$ for some $x \in M$. Additionally, I saw that $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = \ln(x)$ verify conditions (1) and (2), but I could not do more than that. I suspect $1_M \in \{1, e\}$, but I cannot prove that either. Any hints would help me a lot, and I want to thank anyone who could shed some light on this problem for me!

Comment: What is the source of this exercise?

Comment: @Shaun The Romanian Mathematical Monthly (Gazeta Matematica), the January 2023 edition. It is published under the "12th Grade" section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume you have a group with the desired form. Conditions $(1)$ and $(2)$ yield some constants $\alpha \ne 0,\beta \ne 1$ such that for all $x \in M \setminus\{a\}$, $f(x)=x^\alpha$ and $g(x) = \ln_\beta(x)$.
Hence, for all $x$ and $y$,
$$x*y = (x^\alpha)^{\ln_\beta(y)} = \exp(\gamma \ln x \ln y) \text{ where }
\gamma = \alpha / \ln_\beta \ne 0.$$
Conversely, given $\gamma \ne 0$, one checks that the formula
$x*y := \exp(\gamma \ln x \ln y)$, equivalent to $\gamma \ln(x*y) = (\gamma \ln x) (\gamma \ln y)$ yields a group structure on $M \setminus \{1\}$ isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}^*,\times)$. The element $1$ should be removed, otherwise it would be absorbing.

Hence, $1$ is the only element $a$ such that $M \setminus\{a\}$ has a group structure with the desired form.